# Why does "ls --all --recursive -1 *.htm*" only list files in current directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, find, ls

In Terminal I do this command:

```
ls --all --recursive -1 *.htm*
```

or this:

```
ls -a -R -1 *.htm*
```

But it only lists the html-files in the current directory...?!

According to 'man ls' that option has this function:

```
       -R, --recursive
              list subdirectories recursively
```

I know from Krusader Search that there are about 40 html-files in the sub-folders... But why will 'ls' not list them?

I might add that I just discovered that the following command does the job:

```
find . -name '*.htm*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works slightly different than you expect. `ls` will list the files and directories that you specify on the command line. With the `-R` or `--recursive` option, it will go into any directory that is specified on the command line.

You do not have directories that match `*.htm*` in the current directory, only files. Therefore, only the matching files are listed.

`find` is probably the most suited tool to find files recursively, but it could also be done with `ls -R` and `grep`:

```
ls -R | grep -E '\.htm.*$'
```

`grep`is used here with a regular expression.